# Ignore all parent canvas group properties except alpha in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

Can I have an element in the child canvas group ignore `Interactable` and `Block Raycasts` but not `Alpha` in the parent canvas group?

In my current setup, the child game object doesn't obey the parents canvas group's fade-out animation. (unrelated, bu I am using LeanTween' tweening library)

[image: Parent and child]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the canvas group settings to that out of the box.

The simplest solution is to call the same alpha tween on both groups.

If you need the child group to be affected by the alpha of its grandparent, there's a couple extra steps:

- On the child group deselect `Ignore Parent Group`
- Move the child group out to be a sibling of the parent group
- Call the same alpha tween on both groups.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script to copy specific values every update. So you set your canvas group to ignore parent groups, then add this CanvasGroupInheritor script also on the same game object, and then set which things you want to inherit (in this case, alpha). Does what I need for my use case, even though it feels pretty dumb.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Studio.Game
{
    // Canvas Groups by default inherit all the attributes of their parent
    // But in some cases you only want to inherit some aspects
    // In that case, set your canvas group to have ignoreParentGroups=true, then attach this script to explicitly inherit from the parent
    // Currently we search upwards for the parent to copy from, but this script could later be amended to accept a reference the the parent also
    public class CanvasGroupInheritor : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private bool inheritAlpha = false;
        [SerializeField] private bool inheritInteractable = false;
        [SerializeField] private bool inheritBlocksRaycasts = false;

        private CanvasGroup myCanvasGroup = null;

        public void Update()
        {
            SetMyCanvasGroup();
            var parentCanvasGroup = GetParentCanvasGroup();
            if (myCanvasGroup == null || parentCanvasGroup == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (inheritAlpha)
            {
                myCanvasGroup.alpha = parentCanvasGroup.alpha;
            }
            if (inheritInteractable)
            {
                myCanvasGroup.interactable = parentCanvasGroup.interactable;
            }
            if (inheritBlocksRaycasts)
            {
                myCanvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = parentCanvasGroup.blocksRaycasts;
            }
        }

        private void SetMyCanvasGroup()
        {
            if (myCanvasGroup == null)
            {
                myCanvasGroup = this.gameObject.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
            }
        }

        private CanvasGroup GetParentCanvasGroup()
        {
            return this.gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<CanvasGroup>();
        }
    }
}
```